# Collecting data from .txt url in Python with strange encoding

Tags: python, encoding, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib2

I am trying to use Python to collect datasets from a list of URLs. The data is in an ascii .txt format. The data come back consistently in a non-readable format like "\xff\xfeO\x00B\x00S\x00", where it should be a set of tab-delimited numbers with a header. As an example, [this](http://wps.aw.com/wps/media/objects/8992/9208383/Data_Sets/Ascii/Chapter1/HTWT1.txt) is one of the simplest pages I'm trying to scrape. The data are from a statistics textbook, and I want to use it to run through the exercises without downloading individual excel files.

I have tried both requests and urllib/urllib2, but they both return the same data. It seems to be coming in as iso-8859-1, but attempts to change the encoding to something like UTF-8, UTF-16, and Latin-1 have all ended up the same. Here is my example code, which at least returns the data structure I'm going for:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://wps.aw.com/wps/media/objects/8992/9208383/Data_Sets/Ascii/Chapter1/HTWT1.txt'
raw = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = []

for row in raw:
    rawData = row.split("\t")
    data.append(rawData)
```

And my output from this code looks like this:

```
>>> print(data)
[['\xff\xfeO\x00B\x00S\x00', '\x00X\x00', '\x00Y\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x00', '\x005\x00', '\x001\x004\x000\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x002\x00', '\x009\x00', '\x001\x005\x007\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x003\x00', '\x001\x003\x00', '\x002\x000\x005\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x004\x00', '\x001\x002\x00', '\x001\x009\x008\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x005\x00', '\x001\x000\x00', '\x001\x006\x002\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x006\x00', '\x001\x001\x00', '\x001\x007\x004\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x007\x00', '\x008\x00', '\x001\x005\x000\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x008\x00', '\x009\x00', '\x001\x006\x005\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x009\x00', '\x001\x000\x00', '\x001\x007\x000\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x000\x00', '\x001\x002\x00', '\x001\x008\x000\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x001\x00', '\x001\x001\x00', '\x001\x007\x000\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x002\x00', '\x009\x00', '\x001\x006\x002\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x003\x00', '\x001\x000\x00', '\x001\x006\x005\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x004\x00', '\x001\x002\x00', '\x001\x008\x000\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x005\x00', '\x008\x00', '\x001\x006\x000\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x006\x00', '\x009\x00', '\x001\x005\x005\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x007\x00', '\x001\x000\x00', '\x001\x006\x005\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x008\x00', '\x001\x005\x00', '\x001\x009\x000\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x001\x009\x00', '\x001\x003\x00', '\x001\x008\x005\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x002\x000\x00', '\x001\x001\x00', '\x001\x005\x005\x00\r\x00\n'], ['\x00']]
```

How can I get the data in a usable format? Using curl seems to return the right content format, but I'd prefer to keep things Pythonic as much as possible.

For reference, I'm using Python 2.7.9 out of habit (working on moving to 3), but can use 3 if that makes things easier.

Comment: Where can I get this [Python 2.9](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/the-call-of-python-28.html)?

Comment: try - raw.decode_content

Comment: or `for row in raw.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it gets the results you want. So if anyone has a better approach just share it.

Here it is:

```
import requests

URL = "http://wps.aw.com/wps/media/objects/8992/9208383/Data_Sets/Ascii/Chapter1/HTWT1.txt"

response = requests.get(URL)

data = dict()

text = response.content.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf-8').replace('\x00', '').strip()[2:]
for row in text[2:].splitlines()[1:]:
    OBS, x, y = row.split('\t')
    data[int(OBS)] = dict(x=int(x), y=int(y))

print data
```

Output:

```
{
    1: {
        'y': 140,
        'x': 5
    },
    2: {
        'y': 157,
        'x': 9
    },
    3: {
        'y': 205,
        'x': 13
    },
    4: {
        'y': 198,
        'x': 12
    },
    5: {
        'y': 162,
        'x': 10
    },
    6: {
        'y': 174,
        'x': 11
    },
    7: {
        'y': 150,
        'x': 8
    },
    8: {
        'y': 165,
        'x': 9
    },
    9: {
        'y': 170,
        'x': 10
    },
    10: {
        'y': 180,
        'x': 12
    },
    11: {
        'y': 170,
        'x': 11
    },
    12: {
        'y': 162,
        'x': 9
    },
    13: {
        'y': 165,
        'x': 10
    },
    14: {
        'y': 180,
        'x': 12
    },
    15: {
        'y': 160,
        'x': 8
    },
    16: {
        'y': 155,
        'x': 9
    },
    17: {
        'y': 165,
        'x': 10
    },
    18: {
        'y': 190,
        'x': 15
    },
    19: {
        'y': 185,
        'x': 13
    },
    20: {
        'y': 155,
        'x': 11
    }
}
```

> **ADDED:**

If you want some code to parse that specific txt format, you can use a more generic script like the one below. You would only need to change the **headers** list according to the txt file headers (without OBS):

```
import requests

def wrapper(thelist):
    return thelist[0], thelist[1:]

# URL = "http://wps.aw.com/wps/media/objects/8992/9208383/Data_Sets/Ascii/Chapter1/HTWT1.txt"
URL = "http://wps.aw.com/wps/media/objects/8992/9208383/Data_Sets/Ascii/Chapter7/CARS7.txt"

response = requests.get(URL)

data = dict()

# headers = ['X', 'Y']
headers = ['Make', 'Model', 'Time', 'Speed', 'Top', 'Weight', 'HP'] # Must be in order and without OBS

text = response.content.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf-8').replace('\x00', '').strip()[2:]
for row in text[2:].splitlines()[1:]:
    OBS, extras = wrapper(row.split('\t'))
    helper_dict = dict()

    for extra in extras:
        header = headers[extras.index(extra)]
        helper_dict[header] = extra
    data[int(OBS)] = helper_dict

print data
```

Output:

```
{
    1: {
        'Weight': '1335',
        'Make': 'Audi',
        'Time': '8.9',
        'HP': '150',
        'Model': 'TT Roadster',
        'Speed': '133',
        'Top': '0'
    },
    2: {
        'Weight': '1240',
        'Make': 'Mini ',
        'Time': '7.4',
        'HP': '168',
        'Model': 'Cooper S',
        'Speed': '134',
        'Top': '0'
    },
    3: {
        'Weight': '1711',
        'Make': 'Volvo',
        'Time': '7.4',
        'HP': '220',
        'Model': 'C70 T5 Sport',
        'Speed': '150',
        'Top': '0'
    },
    4: {
        'Weight': '1680',
        'Make': 'Saab',
        'Time': '7.9',
        'HP': '247',
        'Model': ' Nine-Three ',
        'Speed': '149',
        'Top': '0'
    },
    5: {
        'Weight': '1825',
        'Make': 'Mercedes-Benz',
        'Time': '6.6',
        'HP': '268',
        'Model': 'SL350',
        'Speed': '155',
        'Top': '0'
    },
    6: {
        'Weight': '1703',
        'Make': 'Jaguar',
        'Time': '6.7',
        'HP': '290',
        'Model': 'XK8',
        'Speed': '154',
        'Top': '0'
    },
    7: {
        'Weight': '1950',
        'Make': 'Bugatti',
        'Time': '2.4',
        'HP': '1000',
        'Model': 'Veyron 16.4',
        'Speed': '253',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    8: {
        'Weight': '875',
        'Make': 'Lotus',
        'Time': '4.9',
        'HP': '189',
        'Model': 'Exige',
        'Speed': '147',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    9: {
        'Weight': '1257',
        'Make': 'BMW',
        'Time': '6.7',
        'HP': '220',
        'Model': 'M3 (E30)',
        'Speed': '144',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    10: {
        'Weight': '1510',
        'Make': 'BMW',
        'Time': '5.9',
        'HP': '231',
        'Model': '330i Sport',
        'Speed': '155',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    11: {
        'Weight': '1350',
        'Make': 'Porsche',
        'Time': '5.3',
        'HP': '291',
        'Model': 'Cayman S',
        'Speed': '171',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    12: {
        'Weight': '1560',
        'Make': 'Nissan',
        'Time': '4.7',
        'HP': '276',
        'Model': 'Skyline GT-R (R34)',
        'Speed': '165',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    13: {
        'Weight': '1270',
        'Make': 'Porsche',
        'Time': '4.7',
        'HP': '300',
        'Model': '911 RS',
        'Speed': '172',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    14: {
        'Weight': '1584',
        'Make': 'Ford',
        'Time': '5',
        'HP': '319',
        'Model': 'Shelby GT',
        'Speed': '150',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    15: {
        'Weight': '1260',
        'Make': 'Mitsubishi',
        'Time': '4.4',
        'HP': '320',
        'Model': 'Evo VII RS Sprint',
        'Speed': '150',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    16: {
        'Weight': '1630',
        'Make': 'Aston Martin',
        'Time': '5.2',
        'HP': '380',
        'Model': 'V8 Vantage',
        'Speed': '175',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    17: {
        'Weight': '1540',
        'Make': 'Mercedes-Benz',
        'Time': '4.8',
        'HP': '355',
        'Model': 'SLK55 AMG',
        'Speed': '155',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    18: {
        'Weight': '1930',
        'Make': 'Maserati',
        'Time': '5.1',
        'HP': '394',
        'Model': 'Quattroporte Sport GT',
        'Speed': '171',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    19: {
        'Weight': '1275',
        'Make': 'Spyker',
        'Time': '4.5',
        'HP': '400',
        'Model': 'C8',
        'Speed': '187',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    20: {
        'Weight': '1161',
        'Make': 'Ferrari',
        'Time': '4.9',
        'HP': '400',
        'Model': '288GTO',
        'Speed': '189',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    21: {
        'Weight': '1130',
        'Make': 'Mosler',
        'Time': '3.9',
        'HP': '435',
        'Model': 'MT900',
        'Speed': '190',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    22: {
        'Weight': '1447',
        'Make': 'Lamborghini',
        'Time': '4.9',
        'HP': '455',
        'Model': 'Countach QV',
        'Speed': '180',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    23: {
        'Weight': '1290',
        'Make': 'Chrysler',
        'Time': '4',
        'HP': '460',
        'Model': 'Viper GTS-R',
        'Speed': '190',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    24: {
        'Weight': '2585',
        'Make': 'Bentley',
        'Time': '5.2',
        'HP': '500',
        'Model': 'Arnage T',
        'Speed': '179',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    25: {
        'Weight': '1350',
        'Make': 'Ferrari',
        'Time': '3.5',
        'HP': '503',
        'Model': '430 Scuderia',
        'Speed': '198',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    26: {
        'Weight': '1247',
        'Make': 'Saleen',
        'Time': '3.3',
        'HP': '550',
        'Model': 'S7',
        'Speed': '240',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    27: {
        'Weight': '1650',
        'Make': 'Lamborghini',
        'Time': '4',
        'HP': '570',
        'Model': 'Murcielago',
        'Speed': '205',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    28: {
        'Weight': '1230',
        'Make': 'Pagani',
        'Time': '3.6',
        'HP': '602',
        'Model': 'Zonda F',
        'Speed': '214',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    29: {
        'Weight': '1140',
        'Make': 'McLaren',
        'Time': '3.2',
        'HP': '627',
        'Model': 'F1',
        'Speed': '240',
        'Top': '1'
    },
    30: {
        'Weight': '1180',
        'Make': 'Koenigsegg ',
        'Time': '3.2',
        'HP': '806',
        'Model': 'CCR',
        'Speed': '242',
        'Top': '1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions for how this could be adapted to be applied to larger data sets (with more than three columns)?

Comment: Just let me know the URL and I'll prepare something. If my answer was correct please consider clicking the checkmark icon to set it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was the right answer. An example of another url is something like: http://wps.aw.com/wps/media/objects/8992/9208383/Data_Sets/Ascii/Chapter7/CARS7.txt
I can adapt the script to take the data by changing the 'data[int(OBS)] = dict(x=int(x), y=int(y))' line to fit the new headers, but is there a way to do it without changing the script manually for each dataset?

Comment: @jtexnl I've added a generic code for you to be able to parse all of those txt files. You just need to change the **headers** list to match the txt-file ones but make sure not to include 'OBS' in it.

Answer (score 0):

try Python 3

```
http_pool = urllib3.connection_from_url(url)
# Submit request, and write data locally
response = http_pool.urlopen('GET', url)

with open('local.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.data)
```

Python 2 - (untested)

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: This does yield a local copy of the .txt file, but when I try something like "data = open('local.txt', 'r')", it gives me the same jumbled text I had before